# Iterating through JSON Result

Tags: c#, json

I would like help Iterating through the JSON response in C#. I want to output the Item.Name.
Do I need to add a property for every token in the json body within my class?

What I have below isn't working. Appreciate the help.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RuneScape_GE_API
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=21787";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result; 
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Parse the response body.
                var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                item citem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(jsonResult);
                
            }
        }
    }

    public class item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example JSON:
{
"item":{
"icon":"https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/1624875191508_obj_sprite.gif?id=21787",
"icon_large":"https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/1624875191508_obj_big.gif?id=21787",
"id":21787,
"type":"Miscellaneous",
"typeIcon":"https://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Miscellaneous",
"name":"Steadfast boots",
"description":"A pair of powerful-looking boots.",
"current":{
"trend":"neutral",
"price":"4.8m"
},
"today":{
"trend":"neutral",
"price":0
},
"members":"true",
"day30":{
"trend":"negative",
"change":"-6.0%"
},
"day90":{
"trend":"negative",
"change":"-10.0%"
},
"day180":{
"trend":"negative",
"change":"-19.0%"
}
}
}

Comment: Can you include the POCO class and a sample of the json?  You are making no attempt to iterate over the result.  Do you mean the deserialization fails?

Comment: I figured it  out..
Add JsonProperty within the class properties and convert to a dictionary with a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, instead of using `JsonConvert` which you have to define an object for it to convert, you can use the class `JObject` in the namespace `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

```
   var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   JObject result = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
   Console.WriteLine(result["item"]);
```

Further more, you can access your json result with this simple statement of code:

```
result["item"]["current"]["trend"]
```

For more information, click [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) for the Newtonsoft docs.

Comment: That's a good way if you don't want to create a class for deserialization

Answer (score 0):

Your class item should have a property class called Item that contains a property string

e.g:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public Item item { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
namespace RuneScape_GE_API
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var url = "https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=21787";

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
     new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body.
            var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, RuneScapeItem>>(jsonResult);
            foreach (var item in dictionary)
            {
                var key = item.Key;
                var RsItem = item.Value;

                Console.WriteLine(RsItem.PersonId);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }

    public class RuneScapeItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}